# How do you use the developers Name instead of hard coding RecordTypeID? Thanks!

Tags: apex, record-type

How do you use the developers Name instead of hard coding RecordTypeID? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [RecordTypeInfo](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm) class to get a list of record types without using a query, and select one based on the name of the record type.

Comment: NOTE: `RecordTypeInfo` class has a method `getName()`, but it actually returns the label, NOT the developer name (API name).  There is currently (Summer 15) no way to get the developer name, nor to get a map of record types by developer name (`DescribeSObjectResult.getRecordTypeInfosByName()`) likewise returns a map by record type Label, not developer name.  See also https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000K9zoAAC.

Comment: True enough, although most of the time, the label is sufficient. I do wish they'd get around to providing the unique developer name as something we can access.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add, I have created a RecordTypeUtility Class.. feel free to try it out..

```
public class RecordTypeUtils {
    public static List<RecordType> RECORD_TYPES {
        get {
            if (RECORD_TYPES == null) {
                RECORD_TYPES = [
                    select Name,Id,
                        DeveloperName
                    from RecordType
                ];
            }

            return RECORD_TYPES;
        }
        private set;
    }

    public static Map<String, Id> RECORD_TYPE_BY_DEVNAME {
        get {
            if (RECORD_TYPE_BY_DEVNAME == null) {
                RECORD_TYPE_BY_DEVNAME = new Map<String, Id>();

                for (RecordType rt: RECORD_TYPES) {
                    RECORD_TYPE_BY_DEVNAME.put(rt.DeveloperName, rt.Id);
                }
            }

            return RECORD_TYPE_BY_DEVNAME;
        }

        private set;
    }

    public static Map<String, Id> RECORD_TYPE_BY_NAME {
        get {
            if (RECORD_TYPE_BY_NAME == null) {
                RECORD_TYPE_BY_NAME = new Map<String, Id>();

                for (RecordType rt: RECORD_TYPES) {
                    RECORD_TYPE_BY_NAME.put(rt.Name, rt.Id);
                }
            }

            return RECORD_TYPE_BY_NAME;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

Then you just call the class..

```
 Id foo = RecordTypeUtils.RECORD_TYPE_BY_NAME.get('bar'); or dev name..
```

Answer (score 3):

I always use

where RecordType.Name = 'developerName'

Comment: Assuming you were asking about soql that is.

Answer (score 3):

I created a couple of utility methods to do this better.

```
//Gets all record types by SObject
public static Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> getRecordTypeBySObject(String apiName)
{
    return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(apiName).getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName();
}

//Gets a specific RecordType by SObject name/Label
public static Id getRecordTypeId(String objApiName, String recordTypeLabel)
{
    return getRecordTypeBySObject(objApiName).get(recordTypeLabel).getRecordTypeId();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is best practice To use "RecordType.Name" via Query

Because ID will be Different in Sandbox and in Production, If you mention the Id in Test class it will pass the method in sandbox but doesn't validate in the production.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm sorry but can anyone please explain how I would use "RecordType.Name" via SOQL Query to replace the recordtypeID I have below? It is for an Account Record Type named "Client". Thanks in advance!

list<Account> acc1=[SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE ID IN :allAccIds AND recordtypeID = '012000000000j8S'];

Comment: Should it just be:

list<Account> acc1=[SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE ID IN :allAccIds AND RecordType.Name = 'Client'];

Comment: List<Account> acc =[ SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE ID IN :allAccIds AND RecordType.Name = 'Client'] ;  Will be Correct